# Tailwind responsive styles not being applied

Tags: gatsby, postcss, tailwind-css

I have a gatsby website that used tailwind as an npm dependency. In `global.css`, I import the `@tailwind` directives.

```
/* @tailwind preflight; */
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
/* @tailwind tailwind; */
@tailwind screens;
```

This css file gets imported into index.js (react component). However, I have classnames like this `<section className="min-w-full mb-10 flex lg:justify-end sm:justify-center">` but the `sm` just does not get applied.

Any idea if my setup could be incorrect?

Comment: Did you include global.css in gatsby-browser.js?

Answer (score 0):

To target a truly small device you just type `justify-center` because Tailwind is mobile-first. The `sm-` prefix targets devices that are bigger than 640px.

```css
/* Small (sm) */
@media (min-width: 640px) { /* ... */ }
```